# Does .NET Core(1.0) support the use of NET35 dependencies in a referenced DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, arm, .net-core, coreclr

I have a .NET Core RC4 project which uses a CSPROJ file to setup dependencies/imports/frameworks. I want to use a legacy .dll called Sifteo.dll in my .NET Core project. This should be made in .NET Core because I want to run it on a Raspberry Pi which has Windows IoT Core(ARM CPU) on it.

I've tried a lot, from importing NET35 framework, which ofcourse doesn't work, to completely building everything into multiple .NET Core(netcoreapp1.0,1.1 and 2.0) versions with no result.

Sifteo.dll uses a System.Core version 3.5.0.0 for some specific Json actions. That's why I need it. Is this mission impossible or is there a way?

Thanks

Comment: Your best bet may be to create an API endpoint running on another machine that will run in the regular .NET Framework. Alternatively, would another .NET Core library give you what you're looking for, even if you have to do some of the work that Sifteo may perform for you?

Comment: The 1.0 version I'm using has the lowest version dependencies which is 4.0.0 if I'm not mistaken. I've just had my time editing the work that Sifteo did. Their System.Timers.Timer is deprecated in .NET Core. So if that's the only way I might do it.

Comment: The web call is the "cleanest", but admittedly a pain. I haven't spent much time with Core, but I'm sure there is some sort of Timer within the library. (If you're feeling ambitious, you could always create a NuGet package.) ;)

Comment: Why not just target full framework instead of Core and run with Mono on the Pi? I mean I hope there's a Mono build for ARM.. Start there first :) edit: Nevermind you're on Windows IoT, no Mono.